# Catalina Music loses equalizer setting

Tags: itunes, music, catalina

I have Catalina 10.15, Music 1.0.0.426 (the Catalina music player), on a MacBook Air 13".

When the song changes, the equalizer settings change.  I don't mean that the sliders move; they are where I left them.  But the sound changes.  (I set the bass high, and the difference is very noticeable.)

Then if I make any change to the equalizer--choose a different preset, or move one of the sliders a little bit--the sound changes back to what I intended.  (i.e. it changes to the setting that I have newly chosen--which is usually pretty similar to what I had before the song changed.)  The updated sound setting lasts until the end of the song, it seems, and then I have to fix it again.

I don't know what sound configuration it's going back to when the song changes, but it's not the Flat setting.

This is pretty clearly a bug, and hopefully it will be fixed soon.  (I submitted a comment on the Apple feedback page, but who knows whether that has any effect.)

In the mean time, does anybody know of a workaround?  Is there is some setting that will stop this behavior from occurring?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a workaround.  I believe that the problem is that each new song reverts to whatever is the default equalizer setting.

The workaround is to set an equalizer preset individually for each song.  You can do this for several songs at once--all of them, if you want--by highlighting the songs, choosing Get Info, going to the Options tab, selecting an equalizer preset from a dropdown towards the bottom of the window, and then saving.  That is what I am doing now.  Catalina Music is a lot less annoying now (but still annoying in some ways!).